# how to send Multilingual String over SMPP?

Tags: java, smpp

I have a French Message:

```
"Pour se désinscrire du service TT ZONE, envoyez GRATUITEMENT « DTTZ »";
```

I am sending this over SMPP and  as output i am getting this message:

```
"Pour se d?sinscrire du service TT ZONE, envoyez GRATUITEMENT ? DTTZ ?"
```

Replaced Characters:

- é > ?
- « > ?
- » > ?

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you convert that text into english and paste here?

Comment: because i want to send that message into French only.